# How to design the config class for creating objects from a family of classes?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, config, object-oriented-analysis

I am designing a library that creates a family of classes and manages it. I need to design config class that is used to instantiate instances from the classes. This config class is just config information.

what is the best way to design the config classes? Should the config class contain the superset of information required to create objects of any class in the family? Or, should there be a hierarchy of classes mirroring the hierarchy of actual classes.

For a concrete example. Lets say I have a library called `animalManager` which creates various animals based on user config and manages:

```
class animal {  // Animal base class
public:
    animal(bool isHerbivore, bool isMammal, bool isNocturnal) :
        mIsHerbivore(isHerbivore), mIsMammal(isMammal), mIsNocturnal(isNocturnal) { }

    virtual ~animal() { }

    // methods that do stuffs..
private:
    bool mIsHerbivore;
    bool mIsMammal;
    bool mIsNocturnal;
};

class snake : public animal {   // Snake animal
public:
    snake(bool isHerbivore, bool isMammal, bool isNocturnal, bool haveHood) :
        animal(isHerbivore, isMammal, isNocturnal), mHaveHood(haveHood) { }

    virtual ~snake() {}
private:
    bool mHaveHood;
};

class fish : public animal {
public:
    fish(bool isHerbivore, bool isMammal, bool isNocturnal, int numFins) :
        animal(isHerbivore, isMammal, isNocturnal), mNumFins(numFins) {
    }

    virtual ~fish() {}
private:
    int mNumFins;
};
// Cat, parrot, elephant, so on

class animalConfig { // User settings to create animals
    // What is the best way to design this class (/hierarchy) ?
};

class animalManager
{
public:
    animalManager() {}
    ~animalManager() {}

    animal* createAnimal(animalConfig *settings) {
        // Create and return animal
    }
    // So on
};
```

In the above example, `snake` and `fish` needs additional config on top of `animal` config. How to represent these config?

Comment: I am completely confused by your animal hierarchy. Why only snakes can be poisonous or not poisonous? Are all other animal assumed to be not poisonsous?

Comment: @tobi303 Updated it to be precise

Comment: I tend to be a bit allergic to OO for the sake of OO, why do you want to treat a snake and an elephant polymorphically? Why do you need one type of configuration for different animals? Btw I am not sure if I can help you, just trying to understand and contribute by asking stupid questions :P

Comment: @tobi303 Lets say I run a zoo. I need to feed all the animals using polymorphic animal::eat. And, do things like animal::clean, animal::tranquilize etc polymorphically. And, at the same time, I need to operate on animals non-polymorphically like fish::swim, parrot::fly

Comment: ok, then why do you want to have a generic `createAnimal` taking a generic configuration as opposed to `createFish(fishConfig)`, `createSnake(snakeConfig)` ?

Comment: @tobi303 Frankly, the `animalManager` is someone else's design. So, I dont the answer. I am not allowed to change that(dont ask me why !). My task is to design the config model. Do you think generic `createAnimal` is inappropriate here? and why?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to have meta_class instances that the factory function uses in config parsing and generating the real animal classes and a `animalConfig` that is little more than a stream. You have one meta_class object for each real class.

```
class base_animals;
struct meta_base
{
  static std::vector< meta_base* > meta_base_list;
  meta_base(...):fn_(...), recognition_data_(...) { meta_base_list.push_back( this ); }
  std::unique_ptr< base_animals > fn_( animalConfig * );
  std::string recognition_data_;
};
class rabbit: public base_animal
{
   static meta_base mb;
   static std::unique_ptr< base_animals > make_bunny( animalConfig * );
   ...
};

// In source file
meta_base rabbit::mb( &rabbit::make_bunny, "rabbit" );
```

Then you have a list of these meta objects that `animal* createAnimal(animalConfig *settings)` can use to instantiate arbitrary animal types.

```
for( auto meta* : meta_base::meta_base_list )
{
  if( settings->section_label() == meta->recognition_data_ )
  {
    return *(meta->fn_)( settings );
  }
  // Handle case where no meta class found
}
```

The input data for this could be a stream containing text like:

```
section rabbit
length X
weight Y
end
```

The animalConfig searches for the text "section" and gets the label "rabbit" (which it stores and returns from `section_label()`), the rabbit::make_bunny method is then responsible for parsing the values specific for the rabbit.  I don't think trying to create an animalConfig class with a superset of all specific data is easier.